# Don't connect points with value 0 in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to connect a line graph while passing over the values that are 0? Here is a fiddle:

```
standard highcharts code in fiddle.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/utnz2b9e/15/

What I would like to have happen is that rather than dipping all the way down to 0 in March and then all the way back up in April, I'd like it to just connect straight from February to April. However, I want to allow them to drag the point up from 0 and refresh the graph so I can't just skip over those points, and since I'm using dates I couldn't have gaps there anyways.

Any help with this would be much appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible.

Assuming the data you are presenting has unwanted 0 values in it, you can easily null them, and order highcharts to connect those null points with non nulls.

This is done by adding the property `connectNulls:true` which is added to the series object.

After that, you can go through your series data, and null the points. In your example Iv'e done that after the chart was rednered:

```
var chart = $('.actualPlansPlot').highcharts();

 $.each(chart.series[0].data, function(i, point){
     if(point.y == 0)
     {
         chart.series[0].data[i].update(null);
     }
 });
```

As you can see, Iv'e iterated through the series points and nulled any zero point, using the generic `update` method.

You can see this yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/utnz2b9e/24/